# Google Sheets =importXML() returns "Imported Content is Empty"

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importerror

I'm trying to import the most common Library of Congress identifier for a list of books using Google Sheets. The XML file for the ISBN is http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?isbn=1433528525&summary=true. XML is pasted below for ease. I want to get lcc/mostPopular[@nsfa] but the formula `=importxml("http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?isbn=1433528525&summary=true","lcc/mostPopular[@nsfa]")` returns "Imported content is empty."

Am I entering the xpath_query wrong?

I know the link is valid because I can import the whole thing with `=importdata("http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?isbn=1433528525&summary=true")`, but that gives a garbled mess of data in the spreadsheet.

```
<classify xmlns="http://classify.oclc.org">
<response code="0"/>
<!-- Classify is a product of OCLC Online Computer Library Center: http://classify.oclc.org -->
<work author="Piper, John, 1946-" editions="4" eholdings="97" format="Book" holdings="184" itemtype="itemtype-book" owi="769061307" title="Bloodlines : race, cross, and the Christian">696100305</work>
<authors>
<author lc="n78072014" viaf="109537817">Piper, John, 1946-</author>
</authors>
<orderBy>thold desc</orderBy>
<input type="isbn">1433528525</input>
<recommendations>
<ddc>
<mostPopular holdings="280" nsfa="270.089" sfa="270.089"/>
<mostRecent holdings="280" sfa="270.089"/>
<latestEdition holdings="280" sf2="22" sfa="270.089"/>
</ddc>
<lcc>
<mostPopular holdings="280" nsfa="BT738.27" sfa="BT738.27"/>
<mostRecent holdings="280" sfa="BT738.27"/>
</lcc>
</recommendations>
</classify>
```

Comment: what should be the output? BT738.27?

Comment: @player0 Exactly, that's what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IMPORTDATA(
 "http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?isbn=1433528525&summary=true"),,9^9), 
 "<lcc>", 0)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'mostPopular' offset 1"), 
 "nsfa=""([^\s]+)""")
```

[image]

Comment: that's perfect! Thank you! I don't have a lot of coding knowledge but it looks like you took the =importdata(), split it up into a table and then searched the table?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your formula of `=importxml("http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?isbn=1433528525&summary=true","lcc/mostPopular[@nsfa]")`, it is required to modify the xpath. In this answer, I would like to propose to modify the xpath for achieving your goal. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='lcc']//@nsfa")
```

- In this formula, please put the URL of `http://classify.oclc.org/classify2/Classify?isbn=1433528525&summary=true` to the cell "A1".
- In this case, the attribute `nsfa` is existing only one under the tag `lcc`. So I think that you can use `//*[local-name()='lcc']//@nsfa` as the xpath.
- If you want to use `lcc/mostPopular[@nsfa]`, you can also use the xpath of `//*[local-name()='lcc']/*[local-name()='mostPopular']/@nsfa`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [local-name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name)